# How to click an icon in div? selenium c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on a div icon. This is the html:

```
<div id="commandBarIconExcel"
 tabindex="0" aria-label="Exp" role="btn" 
class="commandBarItems__container"></div>
```

What i have tried:

1. `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#commandBarIconExcel")).Click();`
2. `driver.FindElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]")).Click();`
3. `driver.FindElement(By.Id("commandBarIconExcel")).Click();`
4. `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.CssSelector("div#commandBarIconExcel"))));`
5. `new Actions(driver).Click(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='commandBarIconExcel']"))).Perform();`

They all give unable to locate the error. Any suggestions, please?
This div opens after we select from some drop downs above it.

Comment: There is no `a` tag in the div in the current html of this post, is this correct?

Comment: Is the page fully loaded when you try to click the icon? It could be a timing issue, maybe the element hasn't been loaded yet

Comment: @Nina is it possible to share the full page you're trying to access?

Comment: sorry thats not possible.... scenario: select name and daterange from drop down , a new div opens , and i want to press a button on that div

Comment: In ASPX pages the ID is composed, have you checked the ID name on debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using JavaScriptExecutor

```
IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#commandBarIconExcel"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", elementa);
```